# Monitor placement not working

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors

Ubuntu 16.04. I have 3 monitors. When I go to Displays to change the placement of them, it switches the placement and asks me to confirm the settings, but the box grays out and the timer counts down from 30 sec still. Afterwards, the monitors go back to the original wrong placement. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What graphics card ? Sometimes it is best to physically move the monitor and set the one you wish as primary.

Comment: Nvidia GTX 1070. I was thinking about that but didn't know if that would affect anything later. If it would switch them again

Comment: You should be able to run nvidia-settings and fix this.

Comment: I'll definitely try that. How would I run that?

Comment: open an terminal and run `sudo nvidia-settings`